# Is it possible to do load balance between database hosts in laravel read & write connections?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, load-balancing, read-write

From the [laravel doc Read & Write Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#read-and-write-connections), laravel can isolate read statements (SELECT) and write statemets (INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE) with below config.

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => [
            slave1,
            slave2,
        ],
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => [
            master,
        ],
    ]
```

In my site the write operation is much less than read operation. And the master instance has 8C16G hard while the slave1/2 has 4C8G.

So it's a waste of hardware resource to make the master instance only response the write operation.

Is it possible to add some balance weight among the master and slave instance to response the read opration?

Comment: Although more of a config solution - why not just swap the instance types so that the read one has more processing power?

Comment: Yes, it's a solution.  But In my case,  the master instance has to leave some room for a period of growing traffics.  And In the future if the traffic is heavy I can add more read instance, and make the master only serve the write operation.

Comment: Have you tried adding the master to the read hosts, this should just (theoretically) be just another database connection.